# What are to steps required to establish a Node.Js Local Server (localhost: 8888) on WiFi though WiFi Router (Passing it through LAN to WiFi Router)?

Tags: android, node.js, networking, server, router

I am currently testing my android app with my mongodb server as well a nodejs server running. I want the server to be availble through WiFi like intranet so that my app from the phone can access the local server. Additionally I need to test how my server handles when more than 1 device is connected?

Comment: Show as some code, results of your investigation maybe. Your question is really low on details.

Answer (score 0):

If your mobile device and mac/linux device (which is running the node server) are on the same network,
Head over to terminal and type `ifconfig`, Under that find en0 or en1 and check the inet value.
It would be something like 192.168.x.y

Now, assuming you have allowed incoming connections on your firewall and your node server is available on port 8888.
You should be able to access the node server at `http://192.168.x.y:8888` on your mobile device's browser.

You can also use tools like [ngrock](https://ngrok.com/). But they create a public tunnel, which IMO not the best option,.